# syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting this above error on the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :email, :username, :password, presence: true { message: "All fields are required. Please try again." }
    validates :age, numericality: { greater_than: 18, message: "Your might be 18 or older to use this app." }
    validates :email, uniqueness: true { message: "This email address is already taken. Please login instead." }
    validates :username, uniqueness: true { message: "This username is already taken. Please try again." }
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, too_short: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed" }        
end
```

Comment: which line is the error?

Comment: remove  the `true` in `presence: true { message:`, same for `uniqueness: true { messa`

Comment: getting the error on all lines

Comment: show the error msg please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every place you've used `something: true { ... }` is a syntax error. You cannot put a `true` there.

```
validates :name, ..., presence: true { message: "All fields are required. Please try again." }
```

needs to be

```
validates :name, ..., presence: { message: "All fields are required. Please try again." }
```